# block url forwarding only containt should be visible

Tags: html, css, widget, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

**My Detail Question is**

I am on testing project. I need date and time on my webpage. Date and Time taken from different website on my Web page. But Viewer should not allowed to click on that; only area of date and time.

*Example.*

```
<center><iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i730viny/n54/tlin7/fn16/pa2/tt0/tw1/tm3/td2/th2/ta1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="121" height="39"></iframe>
</center>
```

Above script will allow date and time on you website but it will need to show this time and date. if any user click on it, it will move to URL "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com". This should be not allow or block. Only Date and Time should be visible.

I have use any script but non of it works.
I am using Blogger as my web platform. Can any one suggest me how can i use.

Comment: why you are using time and date ? on the server it has anchor tag. you can use javascript time and date
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock_start.asp

Comment: General Hack ! Set `cursor-pointer: none;` on that div